# Show subcategory of all Wordpress main category

Tags: wordpress, categories

I want to show the hierarchical list of categories but I want to show all category and its subcategory

```
<ul>
   <li ><a href="#">Main category</a>
    <ul >
     <li ><a href="#">Sub cat 1</a></li>
     <li ><a href="#">Sub cat 2</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Sub cat 3</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Please help me...?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php wp_list_categories('style=list&depth=0'); ?>
```

look for more arguments here :
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories